# How to add sidebar slide menu to existing app (without storyboard)

Tags: ios, menu, sidebar

Does anyone know how I can implement a sidebar slide menu in an exiting app (without using storyboard)?

I have found `SWRevealViewController`, but all instructions are for a new app and an app with storyboards. I can't find any instructions for implementing it in an existing app, nor instructions for implementing it without storyboards.

I have a `UINavigationControler` with a `rootViewController` which is a `tableViewController`, but now I want to add a sidebar menu to the app.

Comment: when you take a look at the documentation you find the following initializer: `- (id)initWithRearViewController:(UIViewController *)rearViewController frontViewController:(UIViewController *)frontViewController;` where rearviewcontroller is your slide menu and frontviewcontroller is the content viewcontroller.

Comment: @RobertvdBerg Did you find your answer??

Answer (score 2):

You can use [InteractiveSideMenu](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu) library. There are `menuViewController` and `contentViewControllers` members of class `MenuContainerViewController` that that can be instantiated from code.

Here is an example:

```
class HostViewController: MenuContainerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.menuViewController = YourMenuViewController()        
        self.contentViewControllers = [YourContentViewController()]

        self.selectContentViewController(contentViewControllers.first!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find link below , you will find plenty of uicontrols here that enables you to implement sidemenu programmatically.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=side+menu

Answer (score 0):

> you are going in right way, you need to push on SWRevealViewController class from your login button and hide uinavigaiton back button by this code.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in Swift 3. Hope it help.

```
            let frontViewController = NavigationController() // UINavigationController
            let rearViewController  = MenuController() // display slide menu

            let revealController = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearViewController, frontViewController: frontViewController)

            revealController?.toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationType.easeOut
            revealController?.toggleAnimationDuration = 0.30
            viewControllers = [revealController!]

            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = revealController
```